# Does the  integral of squared Shah function exist?

Tags: analysis

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi ixsk}$$
$k$ integer.
Does this integral exist?
$$\int_{0}^{1}(f(x))^{2}dx$$

Comment: Have you tried proving continuity of $f^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is, to have a meaning for $f(x)^2$, having in mind that the "Shah function" is merely a distribution (also known as [Dirac comb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb)). It is known that it is notoriously difficult to have a proper notion for the [multiplication of distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Problem_of_multiplication) and I do not know a proper way of multiplying a $\delta$ with itself.